# Type 'Promise<Products | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Products>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с промисами.
Возникает такая ошибка при запуске приложения -

> Type `'Promise<Products | undefined>'` is not assignable to type     `'Promise<Products>'`.

Вот код компонента `product.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Products } from "./products";

let products = [
    new Product(1, "Product_1", "English"),
    new Product(2, "Product_2", "Spanish"),
    new Product(3, "Product_3", "Ukrainian"),
    new Product(4, "Product_4", "French")
];

let productsPromise = Promise.resolve(products);

@Injectable()
export class ProductsService {

    getAll(): Promise<Products[]> {
        return productsPromise;
    }

    getProduct(id: number): Promise<Product> {
        return productsPromise   // здесь ошибка!!!
            .then(products => products.find(x => x.id == id));
    }
}
```

Файл product.ts:

```
export class Product {
    constructor(public id?: number,
        public value?: string,
        public language?: string) { }
}
```

---

Появляется ошибка в связанном с этим компоненте

> Error: src/app/product-details/product-details.component.ts:30:33 -
> error TS2322: Type 'Product | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product'.

```
30 .then(result => this.product = result);    
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit { 
    product: Product = new Product();
    constructor(private router: Router, 
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
        private service: ProductService) { } 
    ngOnInit() { 
        this.activatedRoute.params.forEach((params: Params) => { 
            let id = +params["id"]; 
            this.service.getProduct(id).then(result => this.product = result); 
        }); 
    } 
}
```

Появляется ошибка в связанном с этим компоненте

```
Error: src/app/product-details/product-details.component.ts:30:33 - 
error TS2322: Type 'Product | undefined' is not assignable to type 
'Product'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
30 .then(result => this.product = result);

export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit { 
product: Product = new Product();
constructor(private router: Router, 
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
    private service: ProductService) { } 
  ngOnInit() { 
    this.activatedRoute.params.forEach((params: Params) => { 
        let id = +params["id"]; 
        this.service.getProduct(id).then(result => this.product = 
  result); 
    }); 
 } 
}
```

Comment: `getProduct(id: number): Promise<Product | undefined>`

Comment: `find` может не найти подходящую запись и вернёт `undefined`, о чём typescript вам подсказывает. так что правильным будет объявление `getProduct(id: number): Promise<Product | undefined>`

Comment: Появляется ошибка в связанном с этим компоненте - Error: src/app/product-details/product-details.component.ts:30:33 - error TS2322: Type 'Product | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Product'.

30                 .then(result => this.product = result);

Comment: export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

    product: Product = new Product();
    
    constructor(private router: Router,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private service: ProductService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        
        this.activatedRoute.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            let id = +params["id"]; 
            this.service
                .getProduct(id)  
                .then(result => this.product = result); 
        });

    }
}

Comment: @Anton, чтобы добавить информацию в вопрос используй кнопку [edit] под вопросом.

Comment: @Anton, так же, перед редактированием, убедись, что эта информация уже не добавлена в вопрос, чтобы не было дублирования, как сейчас :)